# I wonder why the getBoardList test using the Pageable object of this WebMVCTest doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, testing

There is a source code

```
@WebMvcTest(BoardController.class)
public class BoardControllerTest {
    
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    BoardController boardController;

    @MockBean
    BoardServiceImpl boardService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(boardController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getBoardList() throws Exception {
        PageRequest pageable = PageRequest.of(0,10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");

        List<BoardDto> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(new BoardDto(1, "Shown Title1", null, "Mingyeom", 2, LocalDateTime.now(), null));
        results.add(new BoardDto(2, "Shown Title2", null, "Mingyeom", 2, LocalDateTime.now(), null));
        results.add(new BoardDto(3, "Shown Title3", null, "Mingyeom", 2, LocalDateTime.now(), null));

        Page<BoardDto> expectedBoardDto = new PageImpl<>(results,pageable, results.size());

        given(boardService.getBoardList(anyInt(), any())).willReturn(expectedBoardDto);

        // when
        String responseBody = mvc.perform(get("/board/all")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("menuId", "2")
                        .param("page", "2")
                        .param("size", "1")
                        .param("sort", "ASC")
                        .param("properties", "id"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse().getContentAsString();

        // then
        assertThat(responseBody).isEqualTo(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expectedBoardDto));
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/board")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BoardController {
  
    private final BoardService boardService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Page<BoardDto> getBoardList(
            Pageable pageable,
            @RequestParam Integer menuId
    ) {
        return boardService.getBoardList(menuId, pageable);
    }
}
```

Based on the BoardController below, I tried to test the method of receiving the pageable object and receiving the menuId as a parameter to retrieve the entire article of the post.

After creating a PageRequest object in BoardControllerTest, I created a List of BoardDto and created a Page object using the PageImpl method.

(Sorry for the lack of posts.)

If you send a request to the address bar on the web in the same way, it will be delivered normally, but if you just test it, an error will appear. Below is the content of the error message.

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
> at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
> at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at app//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at app//org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
> at app//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> at app//org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
> at app//org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at app//org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:199)
> at app//com.inhabas.api.controller.BoardControllerTest.getBoardList(BoardControllerTest.java:125)
> at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base@11.0.12/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@11.0.12/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@11.0.12/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

Please Help ,, :(

Comment: Your test is wrong, you should `@Autowire` the `MockMvc` and not create it in your `setup` method (remove it actually). Also use `BoardService` with `@MockBean` instead of the `BoardServiceImpl` in your test. Finally, to make your tests more robust, I would rewrite the assert to assert the result with properties instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

```
 @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(boardController)
                .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                .setViewResolvers(new ViewResolver() {
                    @Override
                    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
                        return new MappingJackson2JsonView();
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
```

I wrote this code on top of BoardControllerTest, and it compiles successfully.